# Jquery set table th's width equal to td's width

Tags: jquery

I have a codepen here - https://codepen.io/mt-ttmt/pen/OZRpdP

Its a simple table with a sticky header on scrolling

The header is fixed using position: fixed;. This removes the widths from the th's

I want to set the widths on the th's so they are the same as the td's

How can I loop through the th's and set the widths the same as the td's

```
$(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var theadHeight = $(".js-table-thead").outerHeight();
        var tablePos = $(".js-table").offset().top;

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > tablePos) {
            let stickyPos = ($(this).scrollTop() - tablePos);
            $(".js-table-thead tr").addClass('fixed');

            var th = $('.js-table-thead th');
            var td = $('.js-table-tbody td');

            th.each(function(index){
              $(this).width() = td.width();        
            })


        } else {
            $(".js-table-thead tr").removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your problem is two fold: (1) you are assigning the widths incorrectly, and (2) even if you are, the fixed header will overflow because it is fixed positioned, and it will not scroll with the table content: https://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/NMRjyv

Comment: Go it working with a fake header positioned on top of the table. I need a way now to scroll the header and table together from left to right - https://codepen.io/mt-ttmt/pen/OZRpdP